# What counters AP Kog'maw in mid?

Tags: league-of-legends

I played a few games over the weekend and I kept seeing a bunch of AP Kog'maw players and they were giving me a really hard time in mid. What are some solid counter picks or strategies I could use against this in middle lane?

Comment: Akali is my personal favorite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V1.0.0.139
**Void Ooze slow reduced: 28/36/44/52/60%, to 20/28/36/44/52%.**

#### Any champion that can get up in his face is pretty useful.

For example, champions such as Fizz, Akali, Jax, and Irelia. **Bursters** are also very strong, such as LeBlanc, Veigar, Annie, and Brand.

However, especially in solo queue, you never know if someone will go AP Kog; so countering with a certain champion does not always work unless the game mode is draft mode or ranked.

Therefore, I will give **tips on how to counter a difficult opponent by other means than just picking the right champion.**

So how do you counter an AP Kog, in the event that you chose a champion that does not counter him well?

#### Use your jungler

AP Kogs tend to play aggressively, often trying to pick up early kills because of the fact that it's harder to passively auto attack farm without lots of attack damage.

Call in your jungler to help gank. If the gank is successful, the extra gold/exp can be a huge advantage. If Kog does not die from the gank, forcing a recall is also very beneficial.

#### Be Aggressive

But not too aggressive. Make sure you are not pushing the lane too hard, or else the enemy jungler can kill you easily. I am saying you should be aggressive because of Kog's high range. If you stay back, Kog can easily zone you, and out-farm you.

#### Start with Boots and Health Potions

AP Kogs, and just Kogs in general are able to take advantage of an opponents poor mobility early game due to his range. Buying boots will

- Help you dodge Void Ooze
- Keep him out of range

And in conclusion,

#### STEP ON HIS FACE MERCILESSLY

Because Kog has no real escape, except for Void Ooze which has been nerfed as I mentioned above. Just watch out for his passive, it's really useful for turning a death into a trade.

Comment: I'm sorry but Kog won't play aggressively early. Early, he doesn't have anough mana to be a threat. After level 6, with tear, kog can start playing aggressive but the range is not that long yet.

Answer (score 1):

Leblanc is really good at blowing him up, but anyone who can do good burst damage against him and get away, or anyone that's good at closing the gap and getting on top of him, like akali.  But really there's a lot of different characters.  Kog is pretty weak early game so it helps to play semi aggressively to keep his farm down.

Answer (score 0):

Fighting an AP kogmaw at mid early game is pretty much like fighting an Ashe early game.

- Is squishy
- Is only good at kiting

So, how do you fight a kiter?
You try to nuke him before he starts kiting.

Koggy's main strategy is to slow you, hit W and outrange you, effectively harassing you.
Staying too far away from him at level 6 isnt that safe, since his range is pretty damn insane (speaking of his ult). That said, the best way to counter such a champion is by getting in his face.

As soon as you get the chance, get in close and personal, CC, nuke and - if you are burst champion - retreat. If you are an AD based champion, keep bashing him. When fighting toe to toe, kogmaw's damage output disappears as soon as his W is off.

Tl;Dr
As AP burst champions: Wait for his W+E combo to end, get in close, nuke and retreat.

As ranged AD champions: Wait for his W+E combo to end, jump in and start bashing.

I know it's easier said than done, but trust me. It takes a while to get the hang of midding against various champions (3 weeks of anivia midding and i know how to fight Leblanc \o/ )

Comment: The main problem here is that a good Kog player won't let you get close and personal. You will end up being hit by a tower or ganked by a jungler.

Comment: Then one simply buys boots, stays out of range, dodges his ult and hopes he runs out of mana. If you cant attack him, farm and gank.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to get luden's echo vs him to not only be able to nuke him more easily but also for the +10% movespeed it now gives.

Comment: That feels more like a comment than an answer.